# Extracting Ethernet Header using XDP

Tags: python, ebpf, xdp-bpf, bcc-bpf

I built this program to get information, namely the ethernet header out of packets with XDP, and while I was using the bpf_trace_printk function everything worked fine.

When i tried to swap to perf buffers and print the MAC addresses they are always the same, as if they were hard-coded.
The code is as follows:

```
C code
struct data_t{
  //ETH
  u16 type;
  unsigned char src_mac[ETH_ALEN];
  unsigned char dst_mac[ETH_ALEN];

BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(packets);

int xdp(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
  void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
  void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
  struct data_t packet = {};
  if (is_tcp_packet(data, data_end)) {
    //eth
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    //bpf_trace_printk("tamos ai lol %p, %p", eth->h_source, eth->h_dest);
    packet.type = eth->h_proto;
    __builtin_memcpy(packet.src_mac, eth->h_source, ETH_ALEN);
    __builtin_memcpy(packet.dst_mac, eth->h_dest, ETH_ALEN);
    packets.perf_submit(ctx, &packet, sizeof(packet));
  }

PYTHON
def callback(ctx, data, size):
    packet = bpf["packets"].event(data)
    result = bytes(packet.src_mac)
    src_mac = ':'.join(format(byte, '02x') for byte in result)
    result = bytes(packet.dst_mac)
    dst_mac = ':'.join(format(byte, '02x') for byte in result)
    print("TYPE=%d;SRC_MAC=%s;DST_MAC=%s" % (packet.type, src_mac, dst_mac))

bpf["packets"].open_perf_buffer(callback)
try:
    print("Listening on IP:", ip)
    #bpf.trace_print()
    while True:
        bpf.perf_buffer_poll()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n Unloading")
exit()
```

Am i doing anything wrong or is there a better way to do what i am attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I figured out that the repeating MAC addresses correspond to my own laptop, communicating with the local router...